# {{ $myArray->links() }} is see vertical

Tags: laravel

I created a custom page for an array in Laravel, why in my view does it look vertical and not horizontal? I want a horizontal view of my links.

[image]

```
  <div class="pagination">{{ $myArray->links() }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.pagination li {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```